# The meaning of $\mathcal M \vDash (\forall y_1)...(\forall y_n) \phi(a_1,...a_m)$

Tags: first-order-logic

This is a question about the meaning of a mathematical sentence.

Let $\mathcal M$ be a structure with universe $M$. Let $a_1,...,a_m \in M$. Let $\phi(x_1,...,x_m,y_1,...,y_n)$ be a quantifier-free formula. What does this mean:

> $\mathcal M \vDash (\forall y_1)...(\forall y_n) \phi(a_1,...a_m)$ $(*)$

Here is the definition of satisfaction,

> $ \mathcal M \vDash \psi$ if every sequence $(a_1,a_2...)$ from $M$ satisfy $\psi$.

Also

> $ \mathcal M \vDash \forall(x_i)\psi$ if every sequence that differs from $(a_n)$ in at most the $i^{th}$ component satisfy $\psi$.

I have two question actually.

1) Are $(a_1,...,a_m)$ the free variables in $\phi$? What if $\phi$ is a sentence?

2) Can you give a definition to $(*)$? What I mean by definition is, "$(*)$ happens if this and this and this happens."

Comment: You wrote "$a_1,...,a_m \in M$", so $(a_1,...,a_m)$ are not variable at all

Comment: The definition of (*) is that for any interpretation, $σ$, for $\cal M$, we have $σ((\forall y_1)...(\forall y_n) \phi(a_1,...a_m))$

Comment: See D.Marker, [Model Theory](https://books.google.it/books?id=3LIPBwAAQBAJ&pg=PA11), page 11 for the definition.